# Saving Excel file in C:\ using interop.excel throws error

Tags: excel-interop, save-as

I have a wpf application and I am saving an Excel file using following code. If I select the file path as "C:\" it throws an error. No other file path has this issue.

Please help.

```
excelWorkbook.SaveAs(saveAsPath, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

**EDIT**

File name: C:\2347_H4141001_axm2312_20110627_042821.xls

The error is:

> The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:
>
> • Make sure the specified folder exists.
>
> • Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only.
>
> • Make sure the file name does not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]   :  | or  *
>
> • Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Try running the process as an administrator.

Answer (score -1):

- Do you have checked permissions? Windows blocks writes to ROOT of drives like `C:` by default.
- The characters ":" and "\" may be the cause, try to use `@` before, like this: `@"C:\nameOfFile`